# Send data and get the response

Tags: python

I'm sure that it's pretty easy, but I really can understand it.
I need to write a script with python. The script has to take a link and send this it to http://archive.org/web/, to be more precise the script has to put this link to form "Save page now":

```
<form id='wwmform_save' name="wwmform_save" method="get" action="#" onsubmit="if (''==$('#web_save_url').val()){$('#web_save_url').attr('placeholder', 'enter a web address')} else {document.location.href='//web.archive.org/save/'+$('#web_save_url').val();} return false;" style="display:inline;">
                <input id='web_save_url' class="web_input web_text" type="text" name="url" placeholder="http://" />
                <button id='web_save_button' type="submit" class="web_button web_text">SAVE PAGE</button>
            </form>
```

And get an achieved link.

I would like to use the "Requests" library, but can't understan how.
Should I make a request first? 
I think I use request.post but I don't realize what parameters I have to use.

**Edited:**

I did like n1c9 has written, it words and saves links but also I need the link where page was saved. When send request to http://web.archive.org/save/(link) it's loadind few seconds and then redirect to the needed link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
url = 'urlyouwanttoarchive.com'
archive = 'http://web.archive.org/save/'
requests.get(archive + url)
```

and if you want the URL to the newly archived page:

```
print(archive + url)
```

edit: if you had a list of URLs you wanted to archive, this would work too:

```
urls = ['url1.com','url2.com','url3.com','url4.com']
for i in urls:
    requests.get(archive + i)
```

Comment: I've checked. It doesn't save a page at web.archive.org.

Comment: n1c9, I run your code with different links after I go to the site and check and there are no saved pages.

Comment: n1c9, you are right it saved. I was mistaken because it does not immediately. Another one question is how to get the link where it has been saved.

Comment: you can't get the link where it had been saved without automating a browser with a library like selenium. but if you go to the save page, you can scroll through the recent saved versions of the page and find the one you did there.

Comment: Oh. I got it. Thank n1c9.

Comment: no prob :) if my answer really helped you, could you consider choosing it as the question's answer?